# Adding collectionView of collectionViewController as subview

Tags: ios, iphone, layout, uicollectionview, subview

I generally add collectionView of collectionViewController as subview to another viewController like that:

```
[vc addSubview:collectionViewController.collectionView];
```

On iOS 8 I received strange behaviour on memory releasing. Dealloc method was not get called cos obviously collectionView was retained by vc. So I changed to this:

```
[vc addSubview:collectionViewController.view];
```

And it works like a charm, except on iOS 7. The problem is that collectionView does not receive touches on the right side. It looks like there is an issue with frame.

I've made a workaround but it's ugly:

```
if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8.0")) {
    [vc addSubview:collectionViewController.view];
}
else {
    [vc addSubview:collectionViewController.collectionView];
}
```

Does anyone know what changed from iOS 7 to iOS 8 regarding collectionView positioning or how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Are you using `[vc addChildViewController:collectionViewController]` and `[collectionViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self]` either side of the `addSubview`?

Comment: @pbasdf No, just adding view, not child controller.

Comment: Try putting those lines in - they help to ensure that touches etc are passed from the main VC to the collection VC.

Comment: I can't. I am adding it to the tableView cell.